# How to test if a variable's content is in a set of values in AIX ksh?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, ksh, aix

I created two directories under `/tmp/`: A and B.

I want to pass each directory name as parameter to a shell script and execute some commands in said directory, as in below script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -z "$1" ]
then
        cd /tmp/$1
        pwd
        ls
fi
```

Now I want to prevent the script to execute when the parameter given is not either A or B. That is, on attempt to run `./script.sh C` it should produce something like `invalid parameter`.

How can I test if the variable's content is in the set of allowed values?

Comment: You mean: _How to test if a variable's content is in a set of values?_ As in here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111508 ?

Comment: yes. Suppose i want that only my defined 5 things need to be passed as parameter only other than that it will say not exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if [[ "$1" -eq "A" || "$1" -eq "B" ]] #mind the spaces
 then 
    #Do something useful here
 fi
```

should do it . For more info on `[[ ]]` see [[ this ]](http://www.unix.com/302264227-post2.html) post.

If you would like to limit the accepted parameter to a list do this

```
array=("file1" "file with space" "file3" "file4" "an so on") # Your allowed parameter list
if  echo -e "${array[@]/%/\\n}"  | grep "$1" 
then
    #Do something useful
fi
```

**Notes**

1. In shells which conform to POSIX standard, `echo -e` is the default behavior. Check [[ this ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). In other words `echo -e` is bashism.
2. Note that you need `echo -e` in ksh as well as I have confirmed in a `ksh 93u+` for `help echo` says :

   > -e        enable interpretation of the following backslash escapes

Comment: We do not have to give spaces  ?

Comment: @Rishu . IIRC the spaces are mandatory just after and just before `[[` & `]]` respectively.

Comment: if [ "$1"=="A" || "$1"=="B" ]then; cd /tmp/$1; pwd; ls else echo "Please pass valid name" fi 







----------------------------------------------------------------------------- I tried to pass AK as parameter and got below ./test2.sh AK ./test2.sh[3]: test: 0403-021 A ] character is missing. ./test2.sh[3]: AK==A: not found. Please pass valid Name

Comment: Its throwing error if i am providing other parameter as well as it is giving else result as well. Why not only else result I am getting?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: `(' is not expected.
at array line . It saying.

Comment: Array declaration in AIX is not working like this . I have ksh . The script is throwing  error. `(' is not expected.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in many ways. One I would use is  :

```
valid_vals="dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4" #space separated valid values.
#first check if command line arg is empty or within specifications; then,
#check if it falls within valid values as below:
if [ $(echo $valid_vals | grep -w ${1} | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "Valid input"
else
  echo "Invalid input"
fi
```

This way you can define all valid values as space separated values. The scheme can be changed on further requirements
Benefit: you can keep the list externalized, and need not touch the script when list of directories change.

Comment: Looks interesting. Let me try it .

Comment: ./test7.sh[2]: separated:  not found.
Invalid input


Its saying separated:  not found. if putting correct input as well. I am using AIX.

Comment: point#1 Do not create directories with spaces in Unix ( especially in AIX) - ex: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/is-space-not-allowed-in-a-filename point#2 as mentioned in my answer, the intent is to show OP how to do, if he expects directory with spaces, he should change delimiter of `valid_vals`

Comment: @RishuA I tested this piece in `ksh` and it works. Mind posting your test7.sh? If this was AIX specific question, consider applying specific tags

Comment: @ringbearer : Well that is guideline which is not always followed though. The better option  is to use an array of valid parameters.

Comment: Thanks ! I understand now :) Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

change your if condition to

```
if["$1"=="A" || "$1"=="B"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that .

Comment: if [ "$1"=="A" || "$1"=="B" ]then;
        cd /tmp/$1;
        pwd;
        ls
else
        echo "Please pass valid name"
fi



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
I tried to pass AK as parameter  and got below
./test2.sh AK
./test2.sh[3]: test: 0403-021 A ] character is missing.
./test2.sh[3]: AK==A:  not found.
Please pass valid Name

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a switch when you want to test more values:

```
case "$1" in
   "") echo "\$1 is missing";;
   A) echo "Ok, A";;
   B) echo "Ok, B";;
   C|D) echo "C and D also allowed" ;;
   *) echo "Nope";;
esac
```